# Can Visual Studio Express 2008 C/C++ co-exist on the same machine with VSE Java?

Tags: java, c, visual-studio-express

I need to install VSE (2010, I guess) Java. Will that installation screw up my currently-installed VSE 2008 C/C++ in any way?

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't even know there was a Visual Studio Express version of Java. Are you sure you don't mean C#?

Comment: @Gabe -- You're right! There is no such thing. I was ... misinformed. Another problem solved :-)

Comment: Nonetheless I have sucessfully installed Full VS2010 with VC++ 2010 Express and VC++2008 Express and C# 2008 Express.  Seems to not be a problem.  However in the case of C++, the last one installed becomes the default application for the associated file types - just something to bear in mind.

Comment: @Clifford -- Thanks, that answers a long-standing question I've been too shy to ask and too fearful to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSE Java isn't a thing. So yes, you'll be fine. You can install any amount of VSE's without interferring with another install btw.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean J# or something like that by any chance?

I would say no. 
I don't use the express editions myself, but have various versions of visual studio on my machine that happily coexist.